# insertOoxml fails silently

Tags: javascript, office-addins, office-js, word-addins

I am trying to insert an anchor-like bookmark, via `range.insertOoxml(...)` or `context.document.body.insertOoxml(...)`. The api indicates success, however the resulting document does not have a bookmark.

The only workaround is to insert an additional paragraph after the paragraph with the anchor. This unfortunately introduces extra line breaks in the body that kills the experience.

Essentially, this fails silently:

```xml
<w:body>
    <w:p>
        <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="bookmarkAnchor"/>
        <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
    </w:p>
</w:body>
```

But this works:

```xml
<w:body>
    <w:p>
        <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="bookmarkAnchor"/>
        <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
    </w:p>
    <w:p/> <--- this is a miserable workaround!
</w:body>
```

Answer (score 2):

thanks for sending this question.
3 issues here:

1. First of all what the XML described in your sample is in  WordProcessingML, not OOXML. The **insertOoxml** [method](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/word/body.md#insertooxmlooxml-string-insertlocation-insertlocation) is expected to receive the full Office Open XML.
2. That said... i found a slightly different OOXML representation for your sample, this it's working without adding a new paragraph, see sample below.
3. Why are you using bookmarks? from a developer perspective its super unreliable to use them, i highly encourage you to use content controls instead. Bookmarks are super easily broken by end users.

ok so first of all here is markup i am using:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<?mso-application progid="Word.Document"?>
<pkg:package xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage">
  <pkg:part pkg:name="/_rels/.rels" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" pkg:padding="512">
    <pkg:xmlData>
      <Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
        <Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument" Target="word/document.xml"/>
      </Relationships>
    </pkg:xmlData>
  </pkg:part>

  <pkg:part pkg:name="/word/document.xml" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml">
    <pkg:xmlData>
      <w:document  xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
        <w:body>
          <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="005C4C17">
            <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="MyBookmark"/>
            <w:r>
              <w:t>provides</w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
          </w:p>
          <w:sectPr w:rsidR="00000000">
            <w:pgSz w:w="12240" w:h="15840"/>
            <w:pgMar w:top="1440" w:right="1440" w:bottom="1440" w:left="1440" w:header="720" w:footer="720" w:gutter="0"/>
            <w:cols w:space="720"/>
          </w:sectPr>
        </w:body>
      </w:document>
    </pkg:xmlData>
  </pkg:part>
</pkg:package>
```

and here is the code:

```js
 function insertOOXMLwithBookmark() {

        Word.run(function (context) {
            var myOOXML = "<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?> <?mso-application progid='Word.Document'?> <pkg:package xmlns:pkg='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage'> <pkg:part pkg:name='/_rels/.rels' pkg:contentType='application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml' pkg:padding='512'> <pkg:xmlData> <Relationships xmlns='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships'> <Relationship Id='rId1' Type='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument' Target='word/document.xml'/> </Relationships> </pkg:xmlData> </pkg:part> <pkg:part pkg:name='/word/document.xml' pkg:contentType='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml'> <pkg:xmlData> <w:document xmlns:w='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main'> <w:body> <w:p w:rsidR='00000000' w:rsidRDefault='005C4C17'> <w:bookmarkStart w:id='0' w:name='MyBookmark'/> <w:r> <w:t>provides</w:t> </w:r> <w:bookmarkEnd w:id='0'/> </w:p> <w:sectPr w:rsidR='00000000'> <w:pgSz w:w='12240' w:h='15840'/> <w:pgMar w:top='1440' w:right='1440' w:bottom='1440' w:left='1440' w:header='720' w:footer='720' w:gutter='0'/> <w:cols w:space='720'/> </w:sectPr> </w:body> </w:document> </pkg:xmlData> </pkg:part> </pkg:package>";

            context.document.getSelection().insertOoxml(myOOXML, "replace");
            return context.sync();
```

The sample code is just replacing the current selection or adding it on the insertion point (a range basically), but of course  you can reuse this exact same method in any object that supports a range 
Let me know if this works for you and happy coding!!!

btw i wrote an article about this that you might find useful:
http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/word/create-better-add-ins-for-word-with-office-open-xml

Comment: Juan - thanks for your answer, but unfortunately it doesn't work.  Let me explain...the idea is to insert an "anchor like" bookmark...that means nothing between the bookmarkStart and bookmarkEnd elements.  If you open up word and place the caret between two characters and let Word insert a bookmark you'll see what I mean.  The bookmark contains nothing it just gives you a point to jump back to.

Comment: cont'd I'll answer your 3 questions (1) yes, insertOoxml takes OPC; OOXML is WordProcessingML, SpreadsheetML, PresentationML. I honestly think it's a poorly named function (2) see my comment above, yes that works, but that's unfortunately not what I'm trying to do (3) there's a longer story here, I use both, the gist of the story is that content controls come with visual behavior that is not desirable for all of the structure I need to mark up in the document. Bookmarks are not only the only other option, but they're in the standard and they have the perfect editing behavior.

Comment: Bookmark behavior is well documented here: [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-or-delete-bookmarks-f68d781f-0150-4583-a90e-a4009d99c2a0?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1).  They also can be shown or hidden by users via "options" menu.  In addition, programmatically they can be hidden from the main view display, even when the user decides to show them via the options, by giving them a unique name that starts with an '_'; which can only be created programmatically.  I have to believe others are using them to identify structure in a document (e.g. a publishing process).

Comment: I posted a [Word Add-in Bookmark Sample](https://wordaddinbookmarksample.codeplex.com/) that inserts Bookmarks into a Word document from an Add-in.  The bugs in Word are documented in the code along with the request to support Bookmarks natively in the API.

Comment: Interesting to know all the details, thanks. The only reason i am hearing on Content controls is about the visual behavior, but do you know that you can change the appearance of a content control to be invisible? then you don't have the visual behavior you are referring too. I would like to understand why is that not an option for your scenario. Bookmarks are super unreliable, and that's one reason why we are explicitly not adding support for them in the API.

Comment: ok, i was able to repro the issue you are observing... i think its a bug in our end! yeah it only inserts the 'anchored' bookmark if there is an additional paragraph.  Let me investigate in more detail.. in the meantime.. once you are able to insert a bookmark, what are you going to do with it? (i mean the API does not support navigating the bookmarks) what is the expectation here? thanks!

Comment: I just realized where you work :).  Thanks for hanging out here!   I'd love to get you looped onto an existing email thread with a few others you work with.  The [Word Add-in Bookmark Sample](https://wordaddinbookmarksample.codeplex.com/) home page has the scenario...please request to join as a dev.  Essentially, because Word doesn't support everything a publisher needs I need to adorn the text with additional information.  Unfortunately, WordProcessingML, due to the lawsuit, can only be extended two ways....see the codeplex home page for more details on when to use CCs vs Bookmarks.

Comment: and you bring up a good point about the visual behavior of a content control being configurable, unfortunately that's not true about the editing behavior.  Bookmarks have invisible editing behavior.... I detail that in the writeup on CodePlex (below the picture).

Comment: ...and then there's of course the fact that content controls have other restrictions since they're represented by full XML elements.  It's in the write up on CodePlex below the picture :).